# why can't i assign one object's property to another property?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

what could i do to assign the value of firstName's property to lastName's?

```
const user = {
firstName: "Someone",
lastName: this.firstName,
};
console.log(user.lastName);
// outputs undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a [`getter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get):

```js
const user = {
  firstName: "Someone",
  get lastName() { return this.firstName; }
};

console.log(user.lastName);
```